Segmentation Fault when pass a numpy array to open3d.utility.Vector3dVector
I want to pass a numpy array whose dtype is "float64" to open3d.utility.Vector3dVector to get points of point cloud, but Segmentation Fault.
Help me, please.
I have searched many solutions but they don't work and I find an article in Internet which tell me that numpy2.0.0 will lead to this problem because incompatible abi, but if I use another version of numpy, other problems will happen.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am working with Open3D 0.18.0 version, and I was having segmentation faults when trying to pass a numpy arrays with Numpy version 2.1.1.
I just downgraded the numpy version to 1.26.4 and it works.

The changes to make Open3D with numpy version 2.x has been recently merged. Please try latest development builds.

Firstly check other library compatiblity with numpy and downgrade numpy version. If still error occure then install numpy using conda.
